# Nginx master process is not generating core fump file

Tags: nginx, centos7, coredump, openresty

I am following the steps on https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/debugging/ to make nginx can dump the core file for debugging
I enable it in the nginx conf and system config, and then restart the nginx.
And then I try to send SIGSEGV to the worker process and master process, only worker dumps the core file but master did not. Is this expected? Is there any way to make master process also to dump such a core?

The nginx is openresty/1.15.8.2, os is centos 7.3, master process is starting as root but worker is starting as abc.
I also already checked that the sudo sysctl -w fs.suid_dumpable=2 is added and effective
the core folder /tmp/cores has the permissiion 0600 and belongs to abc user.

Both worker and master process of nginx should dump the core file under the /tmp/cores folder